# Falcor with java backend server

Tags: netflix, falcor, falcor-router

I recently started looking into the falcor library from Netflix and trying a proof of concept based on our data.

I have been looking at this library with some interest and although there are tons of examples of configuring and working with routes on a node server there isn't much information for doing the same on a java server. Although I have the knowledge of the libraries availability, but again not much information online. Is there a reference available on how to go about using falcor router with a java server.

Comment: There is a java client for falcor which netflix uses in its android app. However it is not public yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Falcor Java server libraries are published on Maven under the [com.netflix.falcor group](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.falcor).  The docs are sparse, though.